# Loading purchased music onto my iPhone 5S

Tags: iphone, icloud, music, file-transfer

I have purchased a lot of music from iTunes on my MacBook. Whenever I select that music to be moved to my iPhone, it appears (on the iPhone) with a "Cloud" icon beside it. As far as I can tell, the only way I can play this music is to re-load it from the "Cloud" - which the phone tells me will cost money. Why is this happening? I have already bought the music! All I want is for it to appear, like any other music, on my iPhone, as a playable file. Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the iPhone and iTunes are connected to the same iTunes store account and are both 'authorized'. Then you should be able to drag-and-drop in iTunes between your computer and iPhone.